# Imputing means using pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the Titanic data set right now, which as some missing values in the "Age" feature. I have the following Pivot Table created by pandas using the non-missing data:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Pclass  |  Sex      |    Age    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1       | female    | 34.240964 |
|         | male      | 41.281386 |
| 2       | female    | 28.722973 |
|         | male      | 30.740707 |
| 3       | female    | 21.750000 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would now like to impute the missing values in the 'Age' feature with the corresponding values in the pivot table but since I am new to Pivot tables I have no clue how to properly hint pandas which values to use for imputing

My first thought would be to do an if elif else approach but that seems rather unidiomatic...

any hints or pointers on where to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fillna`

```
Originaldf=Originaldf.set_index(['Pclass','Sex']).Age.fillna(piv.Age).reset_index()
```

Comment: nice! just so everyone else uses the same code I did: training[['Pclass','Sex','Age']] = training.set_index(['Pclass','Sex']).Age.fillna(table.Age).reset_index()